# Angular PWA Offline Storage

Tags: progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker, angular8

I’m building a new web application which needs to work seamlessly even when there is no internet connection. I’ve selected Angular and am building a PWA as it comes with built-in functionality to make the application work offline. So far, I have the service worker working perfectly and driven by the manifest file, this very nicely caches the static content and I’ve set it to cache a bunch of API requests which I want to use whilst the application is offline.

In addition to this, I’ve used localStorage to store attempts to invoke put, post and delete API requests when the user is offline. Once the internet connection is re-established, the requests stored in localStorage are sent to the server.

This far in my proof of concept, the user can access content whilst offline, edit data and the data gets synced with the server once the user’s internet connection is re-established. This is where my quandary begins though. There is API request data cached automatically by the service worker as defined in the manifest file, and there is a separate store of data for data edits whilst offline. This leads to a situation where the user edits some data, saves the data, refreshes the page and the data is served by the service worker cached API.

Is there a built in mechanism to update API data cached automatically by the service worker? I don’t fancy trying to unpick this manually as it seems hacky and I can’t imagine it’ll be future proof as service workers evolve.

If there isn’t a standard way to achieve what I need to do, is it common for developers to take full control of offline data by storing it all in IndexedDB/localStorage manually? i.e. I could invoke API requests and write some code which caches the results in a structured format in IndexedDB to form an offline database, then writes back to the offline database whenever the user edits some data, and uploads any data edits when the user is back online. I don’t envisage any technical problems with doing this, it just seems like a lot of effort to achieve something which I was hoping to be standard functionality.

I’m fairly new to developing with Angular, but have many years of other development experience. So please forgive me if I’m asking obvious questions, I just can’t seem to find a good article on best practices for working with data storage with service workers.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a project where my users can edit local data when they are offline and I use [`Cloud Firestore`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) to have a local database cached available. If I understood you correctly, this would be exactly your requirement.

The benefit of this solution is that with just one line of code, you get not only a local db, but also all the changes made offline are automatically synchronised with the server once the client gets online again.

```
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence() 
  .catch(function(err) {
      // log the error
  });

// Subsequent queries will use persistence, if it was enabled successfully
```

If using this NoSQL database is an option for you I would go with it, otherwise you need to implement the local updates by yourself as there is not a built in solution for that.